# How to use a variable within a Set @var = Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Why doesn't this work? (**NOW SOLVED**)

```
Declare @var1 Varchar(10)
Set @var1 = 'Value 1'

Declare @var2 Int
Set @var2 = (Select [IntValue]
             From [TableOfValues]
             Where [StringValue] = @var1
            )

Select @var1, [IntValue]

From [TableOfValues]
```

But this does...

```
Declare @var1 Varchar(10)
Set @var1 = 'Value 1'

Declare @var2 Int
Set @var2 = (Select [IntValue]
             From [TableOfValues]
             Where [StringValue] = 'Value 1'
            )

Select @var1, [IntValue]

From [TableOfValues]
```

I assume it's something to do with the query in the brackets running first, but how do I get my previously defined variable in there?  This is obviously a simplified version of a much bigger query.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** The above does work, but the variable in the real query was longer than 10 chars.  Silly mistake I know, but I've been staring at code all day.  Sorry to have wasted anyone's time.

Comment: If this is a simplified version of a much bigger query, might some code not shown here change `@var1`?

Comment: I think we need to see the data. Both queries work when I modified and pointed to my dataset. They both return same result.

Comment: It also works for me when I changed the table to `sys.objects` and the INT column to `[object_id]` and the [StringValue] column to be `[name]`. Please explain what "doesn't work" means. Did you get an error? If yes, please post the exact error message. Did you mean to use @var1 instead of @var2 in the final SELECT? I don't see where you are checking the value of @var after doing the `SET @var2 = ...`.

Comment: In an attempt to give you some sample data, I realised the problem, and it was related to the VarChar declaration after all.  I couldn't get it to not work with the sample data, then realised the real variable was actually longer than 10 characters.  Changed it to VarChar(100) and it works both ways.  Thanks for your help and sorry to have wasted your time with such a silly mistake. Credit to @NoDisplayName for posting the VarChar answer first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default if you don't mention size of `varchar` in declaration then it will be `1`  So in `@var1` only `'V'` will be stored obviously you won't get the desired result. Try changing your **declaration** like this.

```
Declare @var1 Varchar(10)
Set @var1 = 'Value 1'
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that didn't make any difference, and the value of `@var1` is correctly returned in the second version of the query, so it's being set, just not used by the bracketed `Set @var2 = Select` statement.  I'll add that in though as you're right in that it was an oversight, just not the cause of this particular issue.

Comment: In second version you have hard coded `'Value 1'` in `where clause`

Comment: @Valiante - How you are saying it is not working show some examples

Comment: That was deliberate, and the only difference between the two.  I'd like to use the variable, but get no results when I do, hence the question.

Comment: @Valiante - I mean show some sample data. It should work both the queries should return the same result.

Comment: In an attempt to give you some sample data, I realised the problem, and it was related to the VarChar declaration after all.  I couldn't get it to not work with the sample data, then realised the real variable was actually longer than 10 characters.  Changed it to VarChar(100) and it works both ways.  Thanks for your help and sorry to have wasted your time with such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is not doing what you expect for `@var1`.  Here is the problem:

```
Declare @var1 Varchar
Set @var1 = 'Value 1'
```

It is setting `@var1` to `V`.  The default length for `varchar` with no length is "1" in this context.  In SQL Server, *always* use a length with `varchar`:

```
Declare @var1 Varchar(255);
Set @var1 = 'Value 1'
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, edited as per @NoDisplayName 's reply, however it wasn't the cause of this particular issue.

Comment: Actually, it was the cause.  The real variable was longer than the example, and was being truncated. So thanks, and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One comment: instead of doing this

```
Set @var2 = (Select [IntValue]
     From [TableOfValues]
     Where [StringValue] = 'Value 1'
    )
```

You may do it like this

```
Select @var2 = [IntValue]
    From [TableOfValues]
    Where [StringValue] = 'Value 1'
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried switching to this method, but it still doesn't make use of the previously defined variable. It only works if I explicitly enter the string value in the query.